# NodaTime IANA Timezone offsets not matching with Moment JS

Tags: c#, nodatime

I recently started using NodaTime and I must say it is a fantastic piece of work.

However, just to test that I am doing things right, I took IANA timezone names from [here](https://fullcalendar.io/demo-timezones.json) and printed UTC Offsets for each using NodaTime.

```
/* string[] ALL_ZONE_NAMES = list of zone names */
foreach(var timezone in ALL_ZONE_NAMES)
        {
            var ob = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timezone];
            Console.WriteLine($"{timezone} --> {ob.GetUtcOffset(new Instant())}");
        }
```

Now, for a particular timezone say `Pacific/Apia`, offset was printed as `-11`,

[image]

but when I tried same on Chrome browser (console) from the momentJS, I got `+14`

```
moment.tz(new Date().toISOString(), "Pacific/Apia").format()
"2020-12-10T01:33:13+14:00"
```

**Am I missing something ?**

Comment: Probably. On the one hand,  both libraries use the IANA Timezone database so if one of them uses an older database, the offsets may be different. What does the database itself contain for those timezones?

Comment: On the other hand though, -11 is +13. Which makes `+14` look suspiciously like DST. [Which is indeed currently in effect](https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/timezone/pacific--apia)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `What does the database itself contain for those timezones?` which database ? You mean `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb` ? How do I check that ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And to add, I am using latest Noda Time version

Comment: The IANA timezone database is one database compiled by IANA and used by Linux, all airlines, just about everyone except Windows itself. Some libraries use the OS's version, some package a version in their binaries. Since Windows doesn't use tzdb, NodaTime has to package a copy, which may be out of date. That's not the problem here though. In any case, you *can* add an updated version

Comment: Your C# code calculates offsets while the JS code displays the current date. Offsets remain the same but the *offset* changes based on the date. Use the *same* code in C# as well - print the current date in `Pacific/Apia`. I suspect there won't be any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Noda Time code, you're using `new Instant()`, which refers to the Unix epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). In the Javascript code you're using `new Date()` which uses the current date and time.

Change your Noda Time code to use `ob.GetUtcOffset(SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant())` to make it behave like the Javascript code.

Note that you can get a full list of transitions with offsets for all time zones in terms of Noda Time results at https://nodatime.org/tzvalidate/generate - and you can specify a zone and/or IANA database version as well, e.g. https://nodatime.org/tzvalidate/generate?version=2020d&zone=Pacific/Apia to just show the Pacific/Apia results using the 2020d database.